# Javascript object gets overwritten when working with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have two for loops which should disassemble one object and write to a new one in a special way. But for some reason my object data gets overwritten with the end result being only the last entry. Here's my code:

```
let j = 0, k = 0, tempCities = [];    
for (let stateKey in this.countries[countryKey].states) {
      if (this.countries[countryKey].states.hasOwnProperty(stateKey)) {
        this.states[j] = this.states[stateKey].name;

        for (let cityKey in this.states[stateKey].cities) {
          if (this.states[stateKey].cities.hasOwnProperty(cityKey)) {
            tempCities[k] = this.cities[cityKey].name;
          }
          k++;
        }

        k = 0;
        this.cities[this.states[j]] = tempCities;
      }

      j++;
    }
```

The problem is that this one gets overwritten on ever iteration of the outer loop `this.cities[this.states[j]] = tempCities`

I need to have the object key to be `this.states[j]`, and I need to have all of them, without any overwriting.

Any advice on how to fix this will be highly appreciated!

Also, here is the sample data I'm trying to work with (originating from Firebase)

```
{
    "cities": {
        "-KuzIBwGCbJhAswAcOTk": {
            "cityCounter": 1,
            "name": "Sceaux-du-Gâtinais",
            "state": "-KuzIBslq88OXpE_L0iy"
        },
        "-Kv1e75Dd2pjnropd63W": {
            "cityCounter": 1,
            "name": "Labelle",
            "state": "-Kv1e724mJTS-6E_DZh1"
        },
    },
    "countries": {
        "-KuzIBoxiP2oksxhxFX6": {
            "countryCounter": 1,
            "name": "France",
            "states": {
                "-KuzIBslq88OXpE_L0iy": true
            }
        },
        "-Kv1e6wxA9RwYyEYO27e": {
            "countryCounter": 2,
            "name": "United States",
            "states": {
                "-Kv1e724mJTS-6E_DZh1": true
            }
        }
    },
    "states": {
        "-KuzIBslq88OXpE_L0iy": {
            "cities": {
                "-KuzIBwGCbJhAswAcOTk": true
            },
            "country": "-KuzIBoxiP2oksxhxFX6",
            "name": "Centre Region",
            "stateCounter": 1
        },
        "-Kv1e724mJTS-6E_DZh1": {
            "cities": {
                "-Kv1e75Dd2pjnropd63W": true,
                "-Kv1eEb3D4pqd7l14KCg": true
            },
            "country": "-Kv1e6wxA9RwYyEYO27e",
            "name": "FL",
            "stateCounter": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question : do you declare somewhere `j = 0` ?

Comment: @dimitri can you modify the code with sample data so I can get idea about the input of for loop

Comment: I would also recommend declaring `tempCities = []` before the loop with the cities and use `tempCities.push(this.cities[cityKey].name)` inside the loop. This is also valid for the `this.states` variable.

Comment: yes, I declare 'j = 0' and 'tempCities = []'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten out your data, as follows:

```
{
    "coutries": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa": {
            "name": "United States",
            "states": {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb": true
            }
        }
    },
    "states": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb": {
            "name": "Florida",
            "country": "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa",
            "cities": {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc": true
            }
        }
    },
    "cities": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc": {
            "name": "Miami",
            "state": "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb",
            "visited_by": {
                "P1yjH4GgcFQcJUHULmTgMLC68w64": true
            }
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "P1yjH4GgcFQcJUHULmTgMLC68w64": {
            "cities_visited": {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```